# I can't adjust the HTML input placeholder font by using SCSS, is there some code is wrong?

Tags: sass

I can't adjust the HTML input placeholder font by using SCSS, but it looks like didn't word, is there some code is wrong ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZicmX.png)

```
<div class="input">
                <p>身高 cm</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="請輸入身高">
                <p>體重 kg</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="請輸入體重">
            </div>
```

```
.input {
        display: flex;
        justify-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;

        p {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #FFD366;
            margin-bottom: 7px;
        }

        input {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
            border: 2px solid #FFD366;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 23px;

            ::-webkit-input-placeholder{
                font-size: 24px;
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the SCSS parent selector `&`:

```
input {
    /* ... */
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        font-size: 24px;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
    }
}
```